# How to use Apache Kafka to send data from one microservice to other microservice using SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, microservices

How to use **Apache Kafka** to send data from one microservice to another microservice using SpringBoot?

Comment: Do you mean communication between two or more Microservices using Kafka?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Apache Kafka to communicate between Microservices. With Spring boot you can Spring Kafka or plain kafka-client API. Well there are various ways to achieve this, and it is totally depends on your use case. You can start with Producer & Consumer API, producer will send records to a topic, and then a consumer (or group of consumer) consume the records from the topic.

Please refer [this](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) for better understanding.

If you need any help let me know. Happy to help.

**Links:**

[microservices-apache-kafka-domain-driven-design](https://www.confluent.io/blog/microservices-apache-kafka-domain-driven-design)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll check it out.